# Fresh UBUNTU 20.04.3 LTS installation WLAN in properties missing

Tags: wireless, button

I am new in the Ubuntu world.
I installed 20.04.3 on a new ASUS laptop.

It went fine, but I don't have the WLAN option in the properties (GUI)
Means: I can't connect to my WLAN.

I used the WIN KEY where I can launch the WLAN settings.
Also that worked. But: I don't have the "ON/OFF" button in the title bar to turn on and off the adapter.

Now I have no clue anymore how to connect to my WLAN.
Does somebody has any idea, how I can get back the buttons?

Many thanks

dau29

It is the first time I am raising a question in such kind of forum.
Not sure if I provided all necessary information to understand my problem.

The Model is:

ASUS VivoBook 14 E410MA-EK724TS

The lscpi command gave this result:

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor CO, Ltd RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCI Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
DeviceName: WLAN
Subsystem: AzureWave RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCI Wireless Network Adapter[1a3b:3040]
Kernel modules: rtw88_8821ce

```
     soft blocked: no
     hard blocked: no
```

I hope I don't did any typing mistakes, as I have to type it manually.

Installing UBUNTU 21 was also not solving the problem.

Comment: It might help if you add information about the exact model of your laptop and if possible details of the wireless adapter.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: You could try installing Ubuntu 21.10. It may be that your wifi adapter was not supported in 20.04 kernels

Answer (score 0):

Use an alternative temporary internet connection (LAN cable, USB tethering, etc.) and then, in terminal:

```
sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms
```

Reboot.

Comment: Sorry I used the answer button. But I am new here, I have to learn the behaviour first.  LAN cabel is a problem, as the laptop don't has a socket for.

Comment: Use USB tethering then. Any smartphone will do.